# How to match symbol in regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm trying to construct a regular expression that would match symbols, that
is, things like function names and the like, according to current major mode
settings (it's called syntax table if I remember correctly). After some
investigation, I have found these useful regexps:

- `\_<` matches beginning of a symbol
- `\_>` matches end of a symbol

Now I think I need to find out how to represent symbol-constituent
character. We have `\w` for word-constituent characters, but I cannot find
anything for symbols. Regexp to match symbols should be something like
(assuming that `\s` matches on symbol-constituent characters):

```
\_<\s+\_>
```

Am I missing something? How to match on symbols?

---

*Note that matching on words does not work for me. Trivial example is
something like `foo-bar` that is a symbol in Emacs Lisp mode, but not a word
(because `-` is not a word-constituent character).*

Comment: I typically use `(re-search-forward "\\_<\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\_>" nil t)`. It works, but I wonder myself if there's a shorter way.

Comment: abo-abo: Ugly as it is, AFAIK that is what you need to do, given symbols can contain both symbol-constituent characters *and* word-constituent characters. You should make it an answer. Mark, you'll want to check the manual to see what `\s` actually means, as it's entirely different to your assumption.

Comment: @phils, I didn't even know that `\s` has any meaning in Emacs regexps, I just picked that symbol for example.

Comment: @Mark: See the Elisp manual, node [Regexp Backslash](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is wrong with 
`\_<.*?\_>` ?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of. Very sensible.